# Testing <Input/> component from Material UI using Testing React Library and the call back function is not recongnized in the onChange prop

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-hooks, material-ui, react-testing-library

Very new to React Testing Library and I am lost to test the input component from Material UI and have access to the value. I only want to test the input value correctly and check if a button is disabled after the user inputs texts. However I keep getting errors on the onChange callback function, handleSearchInput. Any help is appreciated.

App.js

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { GlobalContext } from "./context/GlobalState";
import "./App.css";
import API from "./utils/API";
import Post from "./components/Post"
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

function App() {
  const {
    searchInput,
    handleSearchInput,
    handleResults,
    Results,
    startIndex,
    endIndex,
    decreasePageIndex,
    increasePageIndex,
    clearSearch,
  } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  const formattedInput = searchInput.split(" ").join("");
  return (
    <Container id="red-container">
      <Container id="search-container">
        <Box id="search-box">
            <Input
              type="text"
              id="standard-basic"
              onChange={(event) => {
                 handleSearchInput(event.target.value);
               }}
              placeholder="Search..."
            />
            <Button
            type="submit"
            disabled={searchInput ? false : true}
            onClick={() => {
              clearSearch();
              API.getPosts(formattedInput).then((res) => {
                const posts= res;
                handleResults(posts);
              });
            }}
            variant="contained"
          >
            Search
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </Container>
      {Results.length > 0 ? (
        <Container>
          <Container id="pagination-container">
            <Box component="span"> Results </Box>
            <Box>
              <Button
                variant="outlined"
                disabled={startIndex === 0}
                onClick={() => {
                  decreasePageIndex();
                }}
              >
                {"<"}
              </Button>
              <Button
                variant="outlined"
                disabled={endIndex >= Results.length - 1}
                onClick={() => {
                  increasePageIndex();
                }}
              >
                {">"}
              </Button>
            </Box>
          </Container>
          {Results
            .filter((postObj) => {
              return postObj.key >= startIndex && postObj.key < endIndex;
            })
            .map(
              (postObj) => (
                <Post key={postObj.key} postObj={postObj} />
              )
            )}
        </Container>
      ) : null}
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.test.js

```
  test("Search is enabled after text input", async () => {
    render(<App />);
    const handleSearchInput = jest.fn()
    const input = screen.getByPlaceholderText("Search...")
    const button = screen.getByRole("button")
    expect(button).toBeDisabled();
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'meme' } })
    expect(button).not.toBeDisabled();
    expect(searchInput.value).toBe('meme')
  });
});
```

error:

```
    TypeError: handleSearchInput is not a function

      33 |               id="standard-basic"
      34 |               onChange={(event) => {
    > 35 |                 handleSearchInput(event.target.value);
         |                 ^
      36 |               }}
      37 |               placeholder="Search..."
      38 |             />
```

Comment: Can you please share your App.js code ? Once you do I'll be able to help !

Comment: Oh now I understand. So it says handleSearchInput is not a function. It seems like your GlobalContext may not be providing the function. Can you check that context to see that its actually defined correctly. Is it ?

Comment: @Bahdcoder it is defined correctly. I don't know how to gain access to it from testing it using the react testing library

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the values from your context in your test file, you need to wrap the component you're rendering with your context:

```
import { GlobalContext } from './path-to-context';

test("Search is enabled after text input", async () => {
  render(<GlobalContext><App /></GlobalContext>);

  // ...the rest of your test file
});
```

It might also be helpful to create a function for rendering with the GlobalContext depending on how many tests you're using it in, ex:

```
const renderWithContext = (ui) => {
  return render(<GlobalContext>{ui}</GlobalContext>);
}

renderWithContext(<App />);
```